# Can i put text after <li></li> tag?

Tags: html, html-lists, indentation

I'm wondering, can I put text after Li tag and will it be correct?
Example

```
<ul>
    <li>Text</li>
    Text here after tag
    <li>Text</li>
    Text here after tag
</ul>
```

Writing such a code will return dots from `li` tags indented and that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: Here's what that shows: http://jsfiddle.net/QBNz4/

What specifically do you want it to do?

Comment: I want dots to be over the text. In this example over the T letter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want dots under what text? what dots are we talking about? the ones that are part of the list element?

Comment: I edited the comment. I need default dots from <ul><li> elements to be over the text that is below. In this example - dot over T letter from /Text here after tag/

Comment: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2hpqgcp.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your screenshot - the following code does what you want

```
<ul>
    <li>Text</li>
    <span>Text here after tag</span>
    <li>Text</li>
    <span>Text here after tag</span>
</ul>
```

css

```
span {
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

And here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2CXF/

Note that the W3C markup validator will throw errors. The `<span>` tag is not allowed as child of `<ul>`

EDIT:

This one will validate (thank you @Ma3x)

```
<ul>
    <li>Text<br />
    <span>Text here after tag</span></li>
    <li>Text<br />
    <span>Text here after tag</span></li>
</ul>
```

You can also use `<p>` instead of `<span>`.

Comment: Ahhh so easy. Shame on me :) Thank You Mate

Comment: If you want your HTML to validate change it to `<li>Text<br><span>Text here after tag</span></li>` instead. `<ul>` can only contain `<li>` tags.

Comment: Yep. I did the same without <br /> but with p tags which is a block element.

Comment: @Tukkan: Yes. With span should work and validate correctly as well. I will +1 this if the validation error is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Using `<br />` instead like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Text<br />Text here after tag</li>

<li>Text<br />Text here after tag</li></ul>
```

Will produce the same effect and make a little more sense semantically if all you were intending to do was break the text down to the next line.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKnVD/)

Comment: Hi. Thatks for the response but this is not what I want to achieve. Look at this [link](http://oi41.tinypic.com/2hpqgcp.jpg)

Comment: @Tukkan - at least this is valid. You just need a little CSS. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qKnVD/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid to have text between `li` elements, by HTML syntax. But what you seem to really asking for is the rendering in your [jsfiddle](http://oi41.tinypic.com/2hpqgcp.jpg), which can be achieved by using markup like

```
<ul>
    <li>Text<br>
    Text here
    <li>Text<br>
    Text here
</ul>
```

and a style sheet that makes the list bullet appear “inside”:

```
ul { list-style-position: inside }
```

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rK8nZ/).